# Losing milliseconds when processing timestamps in array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, datetime, milliseconds

I am crunching numbers with VBA in Excel using data imported from a text file.  The timestamp data is in the form, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss.000", and the number format is set to "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss.000" for the whole column.  After import, the imported column matches the text file exactly (e.g., 16-Mar-2020 16:10:15.175).

As part of the number-crunching, I read the imported column into a variant array called timestamp:

```
Dim timestamp As Variant
timestamp = Range(.Cells(1, Timestamp_Column), .Cells(NumRows, Timestamp_Column))
```

When I examine the data with a breakpoint, it is formatted as a date, but no timestamp is visible.  It is formatted as: #16-Mar-20 4:10:15 PM#

I then paste it into a destination sheet that has the same number format assigned as the original data:

```
Private Function FillColumnData(theArray As Variant, transpose As Boolean, _
  sheetname As String, destCol As Integer) As Variant

Dim destColRange As Range
Dim tempArray as Variant
Dim maxrow As Long

maxrow = NumRows()

' Transpose the array?
If (transpose) Then
    tempArray = TransposeArray(theArray) ' Transpose the array
Else
    tempArray = theArray ' The timestamp array is not transposed
End If

With Sheets(sheetname)
    Set destColRange = .Columns(destCol)
    Set destColRange = destColRange.resize(maxrow, 1)
    destColRange.value = tempArray
End With
```

The resulting column is complete and matches the original column data, except all the millisecond values are 0: e.g., original = "16-Mar-2020 16:10:15.175"; copy = "16-Mar-2020 16:10:15.000".

Is there something I could force when pasting the array back to the destination sheet?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing dates to/from VBA/worksheet is sometimes tricky.  Excel stores dates as serial numbers with `1` = `1-Jan-1900`.  VBA as an explicit Date data type.

Easiest would be to replace your assignment statement with:

```
timestamp = Range(.Cells(1, Timestamp_Column), .Cells(NumRows, Timestamp_Column)).Value2
```

That way you are passing a Double rather than a Date data type.

*An alternative would be to loop through your timestamp array, replacing each element with `CDbl(timestamp(x,y))`, but it seems more efficient to access that value directly using the `Value2` property.*

That will provide the unformatted value and include the milliseconds

**Proof of Concept Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub dtStuff()
    Dim R As Range: Set R = Range("A1:a2")
    Dim v, w
    v = R
    w = R.Value2

    With R.Offset(0, 1)
        .NumberFormat = R.NumberFormat
        .Value = v
    End With

    With R.Offset(0, 2)
        .NumberFormat = R.NumberFormat
        .Value = w
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, this works as advertised.  I have a follow-up question now as this only fixed half my problem (storing the data).  I want to display the timestamp in a userform.  Specifically, I want to display a start time and a stop time in a label control:

Comment: ```
.lStartTime.Caption = Format([ChartsStartTime], "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss.000").
```
ChartsStartTime is a named range and the result is the milliseconds always display ".000".  This is the same format used for the column where the timestamp data is stored.Is there a different way to do this for a form?

Comment: I've found the answer in another post which explained that Format() does not handle milliseconds:
Dim dateDbl as Double, dateStr as String

dateDbl = CDbl([ChartsStartTime])
dateStr = Application.Text(dateDbl, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss.000")

Comment: @AlG Off the top of my head, I'm not sure that format as an argument for the VBA format function will do what you want.  Try `WorksheetFunction.Text([ChartsStartTime], "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss.000")` instead. And if that doesn't work, suggest you open a new question.

Comment: @AlG Looks like our posts crossed. But if you are using the worksheet function, you don't need to do all those date-double-string conversions.